# Hide First Value on Axis in Excel Chart

Tags: excel, charts

I have an Excel chart that has a reversed scale on it (`Values in reverse order`). In this instance, the values are going from 6 to 1 and I would like to able to suppress/hide the `6` value from the chart.

These are my current `Primary Horizontal Axis` options:

[image]

This is what the chart currently looks like:

[image]

And this is what I would like it to look like (I have removed the 6 using an image editor):

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: I do not think Excel offers a way to choose individual tick lines what what axis value gets shown (or not shown).  However, if your chart always remains the same size and the same position on the worksheet that is hosting it, you can draw a small white square over that axis label using the Excel drawing tools.  Then it is always hidden.  A kludgy solution at best of course, but I've done that before.

Comment: Please try setting `Maximum` to `5.999`

Comment: @cybermike Cunning idea - thank you :)

Comment: @user3964075 This works thank you! Please add it as an answer so i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try setting `Maximum` to `5.999`.